# jquery tabs using radio button checked instead of link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to do jquery tabs but this time i want the tabs toggle depend on radio button check not just a link click this is the normal jquery tabs

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
  <ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-html">HTML Markup</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-js">Required JS</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-css">Example CSS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs1-html">
    <h2>HTML Markup for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs1-js">
    <h2>JS for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs1-css">
    <h2>CSS Styles for these tabs</h2>
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.hashchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$('#tab-container').easytabs();


.etabs { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.tab { display: inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; background: #eee; border: solid 1px #999; border-bottom: none; -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
.tab a { font-size: 14px; line-height: 2em; display: block; padding: 0 10px; outline: none; }
.tab a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.tab.active { background: #fff; padding-top: 6px; position: relative; top: 1px; border-color: #666; }
.tab a.active { font-weight: bold; }
.tab-container .panel-container { background: #fff; border: solid #666 1px; padding: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; }
```

here the link for this toutrial ----- http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-css

i want to make like this tabs but instead of make the action happened when click on the tabs links i want to put radio button and this action happened when the radio checked but i don't know how

here a link for other example for the normal jquery tabs http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that the only requirement to use easytabs is a list with `a` elements. I guess the api doesn't really require `a` elements but listens on an url change of the hash part. What you could do is basically simulate this behavior by manually setting the url when you click on a radio button.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="tab-radio-buttons">
    <li><input type="radio" data-href="tab-1" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" data-href="tab-2" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" data-href="tab-3" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#tab-radio-buttons input").click(function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("data-href");
});
```